# Why won't SciPy's minimize function work when linprog will?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have 3,787 nodes and 23,292 arcs. These nodes can be connected by the arcs. I was able to solve this problem with SciPy's linear programming solver, `linprog`, by using the dot products of utility and the solution as the objective function and stacking two matrices like this:

```
# nodes and arcs are already set

# Objective coefficients
coefficients = np.array(
    [pair_utility[(node1, node2)] for (node1, node2) in arcs]
)

A = # constraints matrix
b = # upper bounds here

# Bounds for variables
x_bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in arcs]

# Solve the linear programming problem
result = linprog(
    coefficients,
    A_ub=A,
    b_ub=b,
    bounds=x_bounds,
    method="highs",
    options={"disp": True},
)
```

This solution was lightning fast. However, I now need to add a new constraint which can only be represented as a function.

This means that I had to change the solver to SciPy's minimize function. Without even implementing the new constraint, I am not able to get a solution because the optimization tries to create a matrix with 5 billion plus elements, which my device cannot handle. Here is the code that creates the error:

```
x0 = [0 for _ in enumerate(arcs)]

# Objective coefficients
coefficients = np.array(
    [pair_utility[(trip1, trip2)] for (trip1, trip2) in arcs]
)
f = lambda x: coefficients.dot(x)

# Inequality constraints (Ax <= b)

A = # constraints matrix
b = # upper bound here
cons = ({"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: b - A.dot(x)},)

# Bounds for variables
x_bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in self.arcs]

# Solve the linear programming problem
result = minimize(f, x0, constraints=cons, bounds=x_bounds)
```

The matrix of 5 billion elements is created inside the minimize function on the last line of the code snippet.

Am I implementing the new function wrong here? Can SciPy just not handle my large problem without a supercomputer and some time? Where should I go from here?

Here is a way to implement the problem with both the `linprog` and `minimize` function:

```
import uuid
from random import Random

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog, minimize

rand = Random()

nodes = [uuid.uuid4().hex for _ in range(3787)]
temp = [tuple(rand.sample(range(1, 3787), 2)) for _ in range(23292)]
arcs = [(nodes[arc[0]], nodes[arc[1]]) for arc in temp]

pair_utility = {arc: -rand.random() for arc in arcs}

x0 = [1 for _ in enumerate(arcs)]

# Objective coefficients
coefficients = np.array([pair_utility[arc] for arc in arcs])
f = lambda x: coefficients.dot(x)

# Inequality constraints (Ax <= b)
A_incoming = np.zeros((len(nodes), len(arcs)))
A_outgoing = np.zeros((len(nodes), len(arcs)))

for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
    for j, (trip1_id, trip2_id) in enumerate(arcs):
        if node == trip1_id:
            A_outgoing[i, j] = 1
        elif node == trip2_id:
            A_incoming[i, j] = 1

A = np.vstack((A_incoming, A_outgoing))
b = np.ones(2 * len(nodes))
cons = ({"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: b - A.dot(x)},)

# Bounds for variables
x_bounds = [(0, 1) for _ in arcs]

# Solve the linear programming problem
result1 = linprog(
    coefficients,
    A_ub=A,
    b_ub=b,
    bounds=x_bounds,
    method="highs",
    options={"disp": True},
)
result2 = minimize(
    f,
    x0,
    constraints=cons,
    bounds=x_bounds,
    # method="L-BFGS-B",
    options={"disp": True},
)
```

And here is the error message:

````
Unable to allocate 38.3 GiB for an array with shape (5141509334,) and data type float64
    result2 = minimize(
              ^^^^^^^^^
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 38.3 GiB for an array with shape (5141509334,) and data type float64```
````

Comment: Where's that 'too big matrix'? Don't expect us to run your cide, mentally or otherwise.  Is that size consistent with the inputs. Overall I think your question needs more focus - for example just on the lp task, or just on 'minimize'.  SO is best for debugging help.  The bigger the problem, and rhe more it depends on background, the less likely it is that someone will spend much time understanding it.

Comment: 23K variables is at the upper edge of what `minimize()` can handle, though you can sometimes get it to work by picking the right method, or splitting the problem up. The solver `method='L-BFGS-B'` can sometimes help when dealing with a very large number of variables.

Comment: 1) I'm unclear on why it's allocating a matrix of 5 billion elements. If it's finding the Hessian, that should only take 23,292*23,292 = 542M elements. Can you attach the full traceback, so we know why it's allocating this? 2) Can you make this example reproducible, so that we can try the code locally?

Comment: @Nick ODell When I run the optimization with L-BFGS-B I get the warning: `RuntimeWarning: Method L-BFGS-B cannot handle constraints`. Posting a reproducible example now

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. On the subject of the non-linear constraint, can you describe the constraint in more detail? There may be some change-of-variables or some other trick that can be used to make the constraint linear.

Comment: @NickODell The original version of this question included the full problem but was probably too much for this board. The original question can be found in its entirety at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r02RlR6ESaJ9db4QeBq1LnBYlEc8cITn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the way I would try to progress this.
1. Use sparse matrices to describe the [`LinearConstraint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html)
2. Use either the `'trust-constr'` method with `minimize` or use `differential_evolution`. Both of these approaches can use sparse matrices within a LinearConstraint (not densifying them*). They can also use NonLinearConstraint functions.

*at least I don't think they do, I'm not fully sure about 'trust-constr'